# How to handle updated hook on edit form

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire, alpine.js

I have simple livewire edit form.

On click edit on any item in the list it open edit form and show data from database.

The problem is updatedFoo because it sets the value of second element based on the value of first element.

```
public function editUser($id){
    $this->foo = 'some value';
    $this->fooTwo = 'some value from db';
    $this->fooThree = 'some value from db';
}

public function updatedFoo() 
{
    $this->fooTwo = 'some value';
    $this->fooThree = 'some value';
}
```

The problem is on edit as soon as the foo is updates from database on click on edit the updatedFoo life cycle hook triggers and overwrite the value of fooTwo and fooThree instead of keeping value from database. How to handle this scenario.

I tried making $fooEdit flag make it true on edit click and create a check on updated hook of if $fooEdit == true then, do action but i want to run it because if user edit the Foo value manually then the updated hook should run to make the logic work because fooTwo and fooThree value need to be change on change the value of Foo

Comment: It is not clear why/how *updatedFoo()* is called. You should post the salient code of both the class and the view

Comment: it will be called by Livewire Life cycle hook i don't need to call it manually @Pippo